# Accessing amazon ec2 windows instance web server from public ip

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, amazon-ec2, wso2, windows-server-2012-r2

I am new to amazon web services and i want to access amazon windows instance from public-ip. I have created ec2 instance with windows server r2 2012 and add a load balancer to listen HTTP requests and also add a elastic ip to that instacne. It also has been assigned to a security group which has all-tcp, all-udp, http and HTTPS from anywhere(0.0.0.0). There is a carbon web server started as a windows service inside with (http://localhost:9443/). what i want is to access it from my web browser. i tried it with this public ip http://:9443/ but it is not accessible from browser. connection timed out,

Comment: Check if Windows built-in firewall is turned off.

Comment: yeah thankx i turned off firewall now and it is working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allowing All Traffic in EC2 Instance is not recommended.

I Suggest You Allow Specific Ports Only According to your Application Needs.

I think You have not allowed the Windows Firewall to allow traffic , Turning it off is not recommended.

Try to Create a Rule in Firewall that will allow you to Bypass the Port in the Windows Firewall.

Refer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753558.aspx

Comment: I will do that. Thank you for sharing!