# Cannot access EC2 on specific port, even though I added security group

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2, server

I created a web application and mounted it on an EC2 Windows instance.

Since it is created with Node.js Express and I didn't touch anything about localhost or port stuffs,

it is being listened on the port 3000 on `npm start`.

After I did `npm start` on the EC2 instance, then I can access it by "localhost:3000" within the EC2.

But when I try to access it from outside the EC2 with its public IP, like `ip_address:3000`, it keeps returning connection timed out error.

As I wrote in the title, I added a custom TCP security group that makes the instance opened for any IP addresses and with port 3000 but it still doesn't work.

What can I do? What am I possibly missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing amazon ec2 windows instance web server from public ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36059050/accessing-amazon-ec2-windows-instance-web-server-from-public-ip)

Comment: Did you use curl command to check if localhost:3000 is working in your EC2 instance? How did you check that `npm start` on EC2 instance is running your app at localhost:3000 inside your instance and not on your local machine?

Comment: Yeah, it works in my EC2 instance. I have Google Chrome and VS Code installed in my EC2 instance and I opened Google Chromed to reach localhost:3000 in my EC2 instance after npm start. Then I came back to my non-EC2 instance computer, and tried to reach its public IP and couldn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things could be going wrong here.

Firstly - confirm your web application is actually running from **within** the instance.
To do this on any recent windows in powershell: `Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:3000`.

Secondly - confirm the security group on the instance allows incoming traffic for your designated port - HTTP(80) or HTTPS(443).

Thirdly - since you mentioned your instance has a Public IPv4 address, it must be located within a VPC and a Subnet. Navigate to the VPC service within the AWS Console and have a look at the `Network ACL` for **that** subnet. It's possibly denying all incoming traffic - rendering your security group settings unused.

If you're unsure on whether the subnet is blocking incoming traffic or not, have a look at these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-rules).